# Excel Formula: how to show D and N depending on the input number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make an automatic shift scheduler in Excel, and faced a problem.

If the input `cell ("Day")` is 2, then the cells show `2 of D`. If the input `cell ("Night")` is 2, then the cells show `2 of N`.

[image: Exemple]

It should be very simple, but I cannot figure it out. I have a vague idea that I need to use an `array function` but have no idea how to put conditional array formula. All I have done is

`=IF(input!B6="/", "/",CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),"D","N"))`

which shows `"D"` and `"N"` but in a random probability, instead of the number that I intended to show.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Is the "/" fixed, or should that be chosen too?

Comment: "/" is fixed. "/" (this means "off') is manually put in cells in a different sheet.  
so first, I intended to check if they have "/" -> then assign nurses "day" and "night" based on the numbers below.

Answer (score 2):

Well, different to what you asked but fun anyway:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution:

[image]

Using this formula (if you have MS365):

```
=LET(wk,C4:C9,
     nd,C12,
     nw,ROWS(wk)-COUNTA(wk),
     i,SCAN(0,wk,LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v=0,a+1,a))),
     IF(wk=0,IF(INDEX(SORTBY(SEQUENCE(nw),RANDARRAY(nw)),i)>nd,"N","D"),wk)
     )
```

`wk` = whether nurse is working (blank) or off (/)

`nd` = the number of day shifts (in the yellow box)

`nw` = the number of nurses working

`i` = an index of those working eg {0,1,2,2,3,3} in the example

`result` = pick the index from a random shuffled array (hat-tip to @VBasic2008 for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77307170/using-randarray-with-rank-eq-in-a-let-statement-produces-an-error)) which might be {2,1,3} in this example as `nw=3`. If the index is greater than `nd` (ie `i>2` in this example) it is a night shift

Copy the formula across for all the days in the calendar.

**NB** the RANDARRAY function is volatile, so the rota will change every time the sheet is calculated, so you will need to save the result somewhere.

Comment: this is amazing! thank you so much! It is a lot more complicated than I imagined too. Another constraint is that a nurse cannot do the Night shift on Day 1 -> Day shift on Day 2. In the example you provided, Nurse 4 cannot do the Night shift on Day 2 -> Day shift on Day 3. How could I add this constraint in your formula?

Comment: @JeongPark Then that means a nurse who works nights on Day 1 will always be working nights until they take a day off? Indeed the rota will end up with no Day shifts unless days off are mandated too.

Comment: Correct. They will be working nights until they take a day off (since they cannot do N -> D right away). After taking a day off, they can either go to Day or Night again. Would this complicate the formula since it is dependent on the previous cell (previous day)? Will it be feasible?