# Using RANDARRAY with RANK.EQ in a LET statement produces an error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to generate a shuffled set, using RANDARRAY and RANK.EQ.

Breaking the formula into two separate calls and putting the intermediate numbers in a helper column works.

B2 = `=RANDARRAY(2)`

C2 = `=RANK.EQ(B2#,B2#)`

But when I try to combine the two using LET, I get errors (as per screenshot).

B6 = `=LET(arr,RANDARRAY(2),RANK.EQ(arr,arr))`

On the cell, a small warning triangle appears with the text: *"A value used in the formula is of the wrong datatype"*.

[image]

RANDARRAY is volatile, so will give a new array on each call, but naively I would expect the function to be called only once, and then RANK.EQ to be applied to the static vector of random numbers.

Comment: `RANK.EQ` won't actually accept an array as the second argument. It has to be a range.

Comment: @Rory That makes sense thanks, though the Help pages say for the 2nd parameter: "Ref     Required. An array of, or a reference to, a list of numbers. Non-numeric values in Ref are ignored.". When is an array not an array? Annoying as I now need a more complicated formula to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Yes - sadly just another instance of the help being misleading (a.k.a. wrong)!

Comment: Mmult which allows arrays may be useful here: `=LET(a,RANDARRAY(2),MMULT(N(a<=TOROW(a)),a^0))` if you want it to be random, but not volatile you need a VBA solution.

Comment: @P.b That's a very neat alternative. Thanks

Comment: `=LET(a,RANDARRAY(2),MMULT(N(a<TOROW(a)),a^0)+1)` is better in case of possible ties.

Comment: How about `=LET(rows,2,SORTBY(SEQUENCE(rows),RANDARRAY(rows)))` i.e. `=SORTBY(SEQUENCE(2),RANDARRAY(2))`?

Comment: While my mmult version returns the same results as RANK, I think you may not want to have the possibility of duplicates and VBasic's version would be a better alternative.

Comment: Ah `MMULT()` is always to rescue!